# Template parameter initialization list with map

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to templatize a class

```
template <typename OperationT, typename OperationCommandT>
struct OperationLink {
    OperationT operationT;
    OperationCommandT operationCommandT;
    bool isEnabled;
    // Param param;
};
```

which I want to use in a mapping class:

```
template <typename OperationLinkT>
class OperationList
{

public:
    OperationList(){};
    std::unordered_map<Operation, OperationLinkT> operationListTable
    {
        {Operation::NOOP, {std::shared_ptr<Noop> noop, std::shared_ptr<NoopCommand> noopCommand, true}},
        {Operation::ERRORCHECK, {std::shared_ptr<Errorcheck> errorcheck, std::shared_ptr<ErrorcheckCommand> errorcheckCommand, true}},
        {Operation::BASEINFO, {std::shared_ptr<Baseinfo> baseinfo, std::shared_ptr<BaseinfoCommand> baseinfoCommand, true}},
```

but I'm doing some error on the init list construction... I get `error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction`
Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: right, forgot to add:

```
// Operation: do nothing
class Noop : public Workflow
{

public:
    Noop(std::shared_ptr<Context> context) : Workflow(context) {};

    bool init();
    bool execute();
};

// Operation: print a banner, together with get the c++ program info
class Baseinfo : public Workflow
{
public:
    Baseinfo(std::shared_ptr<Context> context) : Workflow(context) {};

    bool init();
    bool execute();
};
```

the classes to be templatized... of course they've all the same structure

Comment: What are `std::shared_ptr<Noop> noop` and friends supposed to mean?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the full error message and where that error message is being produced from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{std::shared_ptr<Noop> noop, std::shared_ptr<NoopCommand> noopCommand, true}
```

is not a valid initializer list for a constructor: you're specifying lvalue types but you are passing these objects, not declaring parameters for a function. You want

```
{std::make_shared<Noop>(), std::make_shared<NoopCommand>(), true}
```